# Python: How to accumulate before printing

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
vows = "aeiouy"
myInput = raw_input("Insert a phrase containing vowels that you want to nullify: ")
lowerCased = myInput.lower()
for vow in vows:
    if vow in lowerCased:
            print lowerCased.replace(vow, "0")
```

I am trying to to write a program (without functions) that prints `h0ll0` when I type `hello` but what I get is `h0llo` followed by `hell0`. We didn't get to functions yet, so I tried to write this code without using them but I have no idea how to make accumulate before printing `h0ll0`. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're printing the word once for every vowel with that vowel replaced. You should replace all of the vowels first before printing.

Comment: After reading the other answers,  I realized I can do that by using the print outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_string.replace("a", "b")` returns a string where `a` was replaced by `b`. So you could store that value and replace it every time, and print it after all the replaces.

```
lowerCased = myInput.lower()
for vow in vows:
#The 'if' is not necessary
    lowerCased = lowerCased.replace(vow, "0")
print lowerCased
```

Comment: Interesting how you reused the variable lowerCased instead of creating a new variable, and even more curious how it printed the local variable and not the global one, that is lowerCased, is this always the case? I mean, does python always overlook the scope of the variable and instead use the last stored value in the said variable? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting `h0llo` and `hell0` is because you are checking every vowel in `vows`, and printing out the string every time it is replaced

This is what is happening:

```
for vow in vows: # checks each vowel
    if vow in lowerCased:
            print lowerCased.replace(vow, "0")
```

**Start for loop**

`a in 'hello'?` `False`

`e in 'hello'?` `True` `replace e in hello; becomes h0llo`

`i in 'hello'?` `False`

`o in 'hello'?` `True` `replace o in hello; becomes hell0`

`u in 'hello'?` `False`

**End for loop.**

Also, the `if vow in lowerCased` is not necessary. You can rewrite your code this way:

```
vows = "aeiouy"
myInput = raw_input("Insert a phrase containing vowels that you want to nullify: ")
lowerCased = myInput.lower()
for vow in vows:
  lowerCased = lowerCased.replace(vow, '0') # overwrites lowerCased with the updated replacement
print(lowerCased)
```

Comment: This is not a full answer. If explains what is going on (kind of) but gives no insight as to help fix

Comment: Well, not to be rude but that's what happens with FGITW answers. Next time just take the time to write it all out. If upvotes are dependent on the speed of the post, it's not a quality question 9.9 times out of 10.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I understand

Comment: @SterlingArcher [FGITW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite-on-mso). I had to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Could just use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s='HellO'
>>> re.sub(r'[aeiou]', '0', s.lower())
'h0ll0'
```

Comment: The professor only just explained import (today), but this seems very helpful and faster from what I can tell. I'll note this down! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `print()` **outside** of the loop, after having replaced all the voyels.

As `replace()` returns a string, just update the result in your `lowerCased` variable.

```
vows = "aeiouy"
myInput = raw_input("Insert a phrase containing vowels that you want to nullify: ")
lowerCased = myInput.lower()
for vow in vows:
    if vow in lowerCased:
            lowerCased = lowerCased.replace(vow, "0")
print(lowerCased)
```

Comment: I tried checking what would happen if I used print inside of the for-loop, and it was ugly, thank you very much this was very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Keep updating the string within the loop, and put your print statement outside the loop:

```
vows = "aeiouy"
myInput = raw_input("Insert a phrase containing vowels that you want to nullify: ")
lowerCased = myInput.lower()
for vow in vows:
    if vow in lowerCased:
            lowerCased = lowerCased.replace(vow, "0")
print(lowerCased)
```

Or, you can use this which is a compact way of writing the loop:

```
lowerCased = ''.join('0' if i.lower() in vows else i for i in myInput)
print(lowerCased)
```

Comment: I was aware of .join but the professor told us to use .replace, we also went through .upper .lower and such.